# NGINX reverse proxy to docker container running web app

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

On the host I have the docker container on port 4012, and in the docker container the webapp runs on port 3000 ( 0.0.0.0:4012->3000/tcp )
So to access the webapp i simply go to http://hostname:4012 and the webpage shows fine. 
I want to be able to go to http://hostname/metrics to run the same webpage from my browser.

While I got this to work by simply adding a location to the nginx.conf on the host:
location /metrics {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4012; 
}

All that loads is the index.html (I see the same html source code at http://localhost:4012 and http://hostname/metrics)
but the http://hostname/metrics does not load the javascript assets needed to run the webapp.
From developer tools I see the non proxied site loads assets like so:
http://hostname:4012/assets/styles.css
While the proxied version that goes to /metrics tries to load like this:
http://hostname/assets/styles.css

It doesn't append the /metrics to the assets like it does to get the index.html...
What am I missing here?
If it means anything, the webapp is running on a nodejs express server listening to port 3000 on the docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the app work that way

```
location /metrics/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4012/;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter 'http://localhost:4012/' '$scheme://$host/metrics/';
    sub_filter '<head>' '<head>\n<base href="hostname:4012">';
}
```

So adding a `<base>` tag to the html helps change `/css` to `/metrics/css`. Then absolute urls are also changed using `sub_filter`.

Comment: Elaborate the issue? You need to check chrome dev tools and see whether it corrected the urls or not

Comment: There was no change. The urls of the assets in dev tools still did not append the /metrics/ with this change

Comment: Can you check the html source code if the `<head>` tag changes were inserted or not?

Comment: It did add the base href to the <head>. But i figured it out.. instead of sub_filter '<head>' '<head>\n<base href="/metrics/">'; I put sub_filter '<head>' '<head>\n<base href="http://hostname:4012">'; and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out this mostly only took care of loading the index.html and the assets called in the html. I am still having trouble with .js and some assets loading. For example, clicking a button gives me errors from the .js file handling the button: 
**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://hostname:4012/report/f03d8662-734f-41e8-80a6-736de6649fde' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://theservercname.net' and URL 'http://theservercname.net/metrics/'.**

Comment: On another app, it's not loading icons or fonts that are called with relative paths within a .css file.. so there is some config that is missing here, can't seem to figure out what